# libpqxx skip connection if impossible

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I have 2 different devices which need to connect to postgres database time after time. If they can't they should work in offline mode until there will be a chance to connect.
I have same docker containers on both devices.
I have a class which wraps the work with db. This is it's constructor:

```
db_wrapper::DB_Wrapper::DB_Wrapper(const char* host, unsigned int port, const char* db, const char* user, const char* password, const char* appname, int& error) {
    
    *managing parameters here*

    this->connection = nullptr;
    
    if (this->connect_to_db() != 0) {
        error = 1;
    }
    else {
        error = 0;
    }
}
int db_wrapper::DB_Wrapper::connect_to_db() {
    try {
        *storing parameters into parameters string 'connection_params' here*
        
        if (this->connection != nullptr) {
            delete this->connection;
        }
        this->connection = new pqxx::connection(connection_params.c_str());
        return 0;
    }
    catch (...) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is the code from the main part of the program:

```
int error = 0;
std::cout<<utils::get_time()<<"    Main: "<<" Trying to connect to DB"<<std::endl;
db_wrapper::DB_Wrapper db(host.c_str(), 
                          port, 
                          db.c_str(), 
                          user.c_str(), 
                          password.c_str(), 
                          appname.c_str(), 
                          error);
if (error != 0) {
    std::cout<<utils::get_time()<<"    Main: "<<" Can't connect to db. Continue! "<<std::endl;
}
...
```

The problem is that I tried to launch this code without internet connection and here is the results:
On the first device program crashed without any errors. It printed `Trying to connect to DB` but not `Can't connect to db. Continue!`. First times the crash happened after few seconds and last time it took one hour before crash.
On the second device it printed the first phrase and only after 2 hours printed the second. But printed and continued to work.

With such results I have two questions:

1. Why the first device crashed the program if connection was inside of try/catch block?
2. How to be with 1+ hours long try to connect?

Comment: ot: `if (p != nullptr) delete p;` can be just `delete p;`. The thing you do have to make sure is that the pointer is not invalid, but thats nothing you can check by looking at `p` only

Comment: The only answer to "why did it crash" is "you tell us by running your program under a debugger and/or inspecting a crash dump"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that `connect_to_db()` function which only confuses you more.

The constructor of `pqxx::connection` will throw a [`pqxx::broken_connection`](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/a00884.html) exception if it can't connect to the database.

You don't need all that boilerplate, all you need is to create your connection and catch this exception.

It would give something like:

```
DB_Wrapper::DB_Wrapper(const char * dbname, const char * user, const char * password, const char * hostaddr, const char * port, int & error)
{
    try
    {
        connection = new pqxx::connection(std::string("dbname = ") + dbname + " user = " + user + " password = " + password + " hostaddr = " + hostaddr + " port = " + port);
        error = 0;
    }
    catch(const pqxx::broken_connection &)
    {
        error = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks.
But how it will help with the problem? `catch (...)` should catch every exception already.

Comment: You can change the catched exception, `pqxx::broken_connection` inherits from `std::exception` so you can catch a reference to it instead, or even have multiple catch clauses, or a single `catch(...)` or put it at the end, or.... It's all up to you to decide what exceptions to catch and when.

Comment: Yes. But I already have try-catch block. And still have a problem. I understand that your code looks better but my questions were about crashes and too long connection time.

Comment: @Dmitry Maybe the crash happens in the code you didn't show (double delete, or anything). We can't diagnose it without a complete, minimal and reproducible example.